# HTML bootstrap code works as expected on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I am testing bootstrap grids with background colors but the same code renders on Firefox as expected but doesn't work on chrome.

This code is just a copy of sample starting code from bootstrap website. I have added container, a row and 4 columns in that row. This code works when I open the HTML file on firefox but in chrome it displays just the numbers as you can see when you run the snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/customstyles.css">-->
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 bg-info">1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 bg-warning">2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 bg-danger">3</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 bg-dark">4</div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stacksnippets.net/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css is a 404 error.

Comment: @Quentin run it again, I was editing

Comment: `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` is **still** a 404

Comment: The live demo in the question gives identical results in Firefox and Chrome when I test it. There is no CSS.

Comment: @Quentin that's is because that's the directory in my PC. Would you please try this on yours?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mbJyb2c.jpg  this is what i get on fire fox and https://i.imgur.com/F2qdTYB.jpg  this is what i get on chrome

Comment: The URL in the address bar is not the URL of your live demo (where you say `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` which is a 404 error). (Hint: Edit the live demo so you put a URL which resolves to the CSS! There are plenty of CDNs hosting it! You're already using some for the JavaScript!)

Comment: @Quentin Done!! Thankyou. I also added this to my code and now it works on chrome. Could please explain why it didn't work with the local copy of bootstrap on chrome while it worked on Firefox?

Comment: Got it! It was because of the integrity check hash. I removed it and it works perfectly now. Thanks.